# Subquery with JOIN, UNION, and ORDER BY, using temporary, using filesort

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql for a messaging system. I'm trying to write a query that will pull the last message sent to or received from every other user, that the user has communicated with.

This is the table that holds all the messages:

```
CREATE TABLE `privatemessages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `recipient` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `readstatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `messagetype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `recipient` (`recipient`),
  KEY `sender` (`sender`),
  KEY `read` (`readstatus`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `openmessagingpanel` (`recipient`,`readstatus`),
  KEY `openpmthreadrev` (`recipient`,`sender`),
  KEY `openpmthread` (`sender`,`recipient`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27587533 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Here is the query giving me problems:

```
select * from 
(
select users.username, users.onlinestatus,users.profileimageid, privatemessages.id, privatemessages.time, privatemessages.message from privatemessages 
JOIN users on privatemessages.recipient=users.id WHERE sender=19 
UNION ALL 
select users.username, users.onlinestatus,users.profileimageid, privatemessages.id, privatemessages.time, privatemessages.message from privatemessages 
JOIN users on privatemessages.sender=users.id WHERE recipient=19 
ORDER BY id DESC
)
as testResult GROUP by testResult.username ORDER By id DESC;
```

The query returns the data that I want, in the correct order, but it is very slow for users with a lot of messages.

Here is the explain statement:

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table           | type   | possible_keys                                                    | key                | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>      | ALL    | NULL                                                             | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                            | 4246 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED      | privatemessages | ref    | recipient,sender,openmessagingpanel,openpmthreadrev,openpmthread | sender             | 4       |                                 | 1076 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED      | users           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                          | PRIMARY            | 4       | chat2.privatemessages.recipient |    1 |                                 |
|  3 | UNION        | privatemessages | ref    | recipient,sender,openmessagingpanel,openpmthreadrev,openpmthread | openmessagingpanel | 4       |                                 | 6490 |                                 |
|  3 | UNION        | users           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                          | PRIMARY            | 4       | chat2.privatemessages.sender    |    1 |                                 |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3>      | ALL    | NULL                                                             | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                            | NULL | Using filesort                  |
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Is there a better query I should use?
Thanks

Comment: Does your query even give the correct results?!

Comment: Yes the query returns the correct results

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT users.username, users.onlinestatus, users.profileimageid, temp.id, temp.time, temp.message
  FROM users
 INNER JOIN (SELECT id, time, message, recipient FROM privatemessages WHERE sender=19) temp
    ON temp.recipient=users.id
 UNION 
SELECT users.username, users.onlinestatus,users.profileimageid, temp.id, temp.time, temp.message
  FROM users
 INNER JOIN (SELECT id, time, message, sender FROM privatemessages WHERE sender=19) temp
    ON temp.sender=users.id
 GROUP BY username ORDER BY id DESC
```